# Trying to write a very simple program involving a password (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, passwords

So I tried out having a password check in my program, the goal is, if the user types the correct password then the program will reply: "You Pass", if not the "You're wrong". The problem is Eclipse tells me that "Fish (that's the password) cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password;

        password = Fish;

        System.out.println("What is the password? ");
        scan.nextLine();

        if (scan.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You pass!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You're wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried resolving the issue in Eclipse's way, but with their method I get the wrong password when I type it after running the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

    private static final String Fish = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password;

        password = Fish;

        System.out.println("What is the password? ");
        scan.nextLine();

        if (scan.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You pass!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You're wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looking this up online, I'm actually reading Java Programming for Dummies, and still no luck, hopefully you can help me, I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Gotta surround `Fish` in quotes `"` to tell java its a string not a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wriiten some wrong syntaxes for it.Try this code.I have added necessary comments to let you make undersatand that what I have done in the following code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String password;

 password = "Fish";  // assigning  value to String password

 System.out.println("enter value");

String temp=scan.nextLine(); //scanner takes nextline entered and assign it to temp

   //  if (scan.equals(password))  is wrong ,you want to compare value taken by scanner , what you have wriiten is incorrect. scan is object of Scanner.Not value taken by it


 if(temp.equals(password))  //if entered value eqauls your assigned       password value
  {
      System.out.println("You pass!"); // else print you pass
  }
else
{
  System.out.println("You're wrong!"); //else  print "you are wrong"
}
```

Comment: It works percetly, thanks! Although, when you say that something is assigned to "temp" what does that mean?

Comment: See . When I do scan.nextLine(), that is method of Scanner class whose return type is "String" so it will return next line entered.I have just taken a temporary string temp to hold that value.As i need to comapre it to your predefined passwprd.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isValid(password)) 
{  
    System.out.println("You pass!");  
} 
else 
{  
    System.out.println("You're wrong!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you're never reading your input in a variable!and then you're trying to check equality between the "scan" object which is of type Scanner.Instead  read input "scan.nextLine();" in a variable say "var" and then call var.equals(password).Please also check that your String "Fish" is null initially which will give you a NullPointerException!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the Java World!

In your program you are making a small mistake by calling the equals on a Scanner object.
Also remember to close the close-able scanner resource once you are done with it.

Please refer the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Password {

```
private static final String Fish = "Fish";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the password? ");

    if (scan.nextLine().equals(Fish)) {
        System.out.println("You pass!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You're wrong!");
    }

}
```

}